# Harmonic oscillator with constant external force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I tried to find the full derivation of the differential equations for the following problem but did not find any relevant resources that discuss external forces with harmonic motion (except damped and forced motions):

"Mass m is attached to a string (which is itself connected to the ceiling) and is a mathematical pendulum if we use a small angle approximation. a horizontal external constant force $F_0$ is applied to the mass m. write the relevant differential equations, and show the derivation for the angular frequency" (the answer is $\omega'=\sqrt{(\sqrt{g^2+(F_0/m)^2})/l}$ ).

I tried to solve this example in the following way:

1. I decomposed the force mg and $F_0$ to their radial and tangent component. in the tangent axis, the equation is $−mgsin(θ)−F_0cos(θ)=mlθ′′$ (1).
2. using small angle approximation, i have assumed that $cos(\theta)~1, sin(\theta)~\theta$, but when I solved the differential equation I didn't get the correct answer.
3. but, if I have written the following equation instead:
   $\sqrt{(mg)^2+(F_0)^2}*sin(\theta)=ml\theta''$ (2) i would get the right answer.

why my first equation (1) is not correct? is the second equation (2) correct? if so, why?

regarding the closing of my question, I don't get why the solution presented in the suggested question ([Harmonic motion equation - non-null right hand side](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265276/harmonic-motion-equation-non-null-right-hand-side)) is the solution to my question.

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: There are three forces acting on $m$, and two of them are unchanging. What problem are you having when you try to write the equations of motion for $m$? (Someone is not going to simply do this problem for you. It will likely be closed as “homework-like” unless you explain more about your confusion and show some work.)

Comment: My suggestion: You should not be trying to find resources working out a similar problem somewhere. Thinking through a problem yourself is a much better way to learn. You should be applying Newton’s Second Law, working in polar (not Cartesian) coordinates.

Comment: Put your work in the question, not in comments.

Comment: @Ghoster i have written the following equation (after decomposing the forces to the radial and tangent axis):
$-mg*sin(\theta)-F_0*cos(\theta)=ml(\theta)''$ using small angles approximation.
but when i solved the differential equation i didn't get the correct answer.
if i have written the following equation instead: 
$-\sqrt{((mg)^2+F_0^2)}sin(\theta)=ml\theta''$
i would get the correct answer, but i don't understand why it is the correct equation.
an explanation why my equation is not correct and the latter is would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

from the FBD you obtain the equation of motion

$$ \ddot\theta+\underbrace{\frac gl\,\sin(\theta)-\frac{F_0}{m\,l}\,\cos(\theta)}_{z}=0$$

from here , obtain the Taylor series   $~\theta=\theta_0~$ of $~z~$

$$z_l={\frac {g\sin \left( \theta_{{0}} \right) }{l}}-{\frac {F_{{0}}\cos
 \left( \theta_{{0}} \right) }{ml}}+ \left( {\frac {g\cos \left( 
\theta_{{0}} \right) }{l}}+{\frac {F_{{0}}\sin \left( \theta_{{0}}
 \right) }{ml}} \right)  \left( \theta-\theta_{{0}} \right)
$$

thus the equilibrium is $~\ddot\theta_l=0~$ at

$$\theta=\theta_0\quad,z_l(\theta_0)=0~ \Rightarrow \theta_0=
\arctan\left(\frac{F_0}{m\,g}\right)$$

so the linearized equation of motion is

$$\ddot\theta_l+\omega^2\,\theta_l=0$$

where

$$\omega^2=\frac {1}{m\,l}\,\sqrt{F_0^2+(m\,g)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $\delta$ to be the angle such that
$$
\tan \delta = \frac{F_0}{mg}.
$$
Then it is not too hard to show that your equation (1) is equivalent to
$$
ml^2 \ddot{\theta} = -\sqrt{(mg)^2+F_0^2} \sin(\theta -\delta),
$$
or, defining $\alpha = \theta -\delta $,
$$
ml^2 \ddot{\alpha} = -\sqrt{(mg)^2+F_0^2} \sin(\alpha). 
$$

We can see that the equilibrium state is $\alpha =0$; and expanding the equation for small $\alpha $ gives the simple harmonic oscillator equation with the desired frequency.  Expanding about $\theta =0$ doesn't help in finding the frequency of small oscillations because $\theta =0$ is not an equilibrium state.

Answer (score 1):

A horizontal force is equivalent to tilting the pendulum and then increasing g, so you should be able to solve this with the Pythagorean theorem in one line once you find the right scale factor, which you have.